# How to use snapshotChanges() inside Object that will render properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm experimenting with **Angular 5** and **Firebase** especially its `Realtime Database`, to do this I use `angularfire2` specifically `v5`, and i understand the difference between `list` and `object` and what are the differences between `valueChanges()` and `snapshotChanges()`.

Let say i have following database structure on my firebase realtime database:

```
"courses" : {
  "ONE" : {
    "AU" : 1,
    "COURSE" : "ONE",
    "COURSE_CODE" : "1111"
  },
  "TWO" : {
    "AU" : 2,
    "COURSE" : "TWO",
    "COURSE_CODE" : "2222"
  },
  "THREE" : {
    "AU" : 3,
    "COURSE" : "THREE",
    "COURSE_CODE" : "3333"
  },
  "FOUR" : {
    "AU" : 4,
    "COURSE" : "FOUR",
    "COURSE_CODE" : "4444"
  }
}
```

Here I want to use `snapshotChanges()`, if we use it on `list` it will become something like this

```
// on app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mycourses$;

  constructor(private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mycourses$ = this.firebaseDB.list('courses').snapshotChanges().map((changes) => {
      return changes.map((c) => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
}
```

while

```
// on app.component.html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of mycourses$ | async">
    <p class="course">{{ course.COURSE }}</p>
    <span class="course-code"> - {{ course.COURSE_CODE }}</span>
    <span class="au"> - {{ course.AU }} SKS</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code **work flawlessly**, no problem at all, as expected.

**However**, if I want to use `snapshotChanges()` on `object`, like:

```
// on app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mycourse$;

  constructor(private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mycourse$ = this.firebaseDB.object('courses/ONE').snapshotChanges().map((change) => {
      return { key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val() };
    });
  }
}
```

and

```
// on app.component.html
<div *ngIf="mycourse$ | async">
  <p>{{ mycourse$.COURSE }}</p>
</div>
```

The above code **won't work**, no error message printed on browser's console, **but** the browser just **won't render** `mycourse$.COURSE` value, **why** is that? **how** to fix this?

Comment: Ok, I don't know angular nor angularfire2.. so maybe this comment is totally stupid... but do you really have to use `map()` when retrieving the data as an `object`?

Comment: Yes it is, since returned object from `subscription` alone are quite large and complex, we want to simplify it by using `map`, and documentation also recommend it.